# Separate 4 digits with : sign using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am working on custom timepicker. What I want to do is: If user enters `1234` it will be change to `12:34`. Problem is nothing happens at all (I am not getting exception). Here is what I have so far:

```
// check time entry
(function ($) {
    String.prototype.Timeset = function(){
        return this.replace(/^\d{2}\:\d$/,"$1,");
    }
    $.fn.Time = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().Timeset());
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
```

HTML Markup:

```
<input id="txtTime" type="text" maxlength="4" onpaste="return false;" onchange="this.value = this.value.Timeset();" />
```

How can I achieve this? My regular expression may also be the root of this. Note that I don't want to use any external mask plugins as I have to apply `hot-keys` on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
function formatTime(s) {
    return s.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/^(\d\d)(\d\d).*$/, "$1:$2");
}

(function ($) {
    $.fn.timeInput = function() {
        return $(this).change(function() {
            $(this).val(formatTime($(this).val()))
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LAbFQ/

Comment: Wow!! that's cool. that's what i wanted. hey is there any expression for restrict user not to enter more than **23:59**?

Comment: @DKM: yes, there is, but that would be too complicated for a comment ;)

Comment: Can you see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAbFQ/1/)? it's having a strange issue, if i use `.keyup()` instead of `change()` i am using chrome

Comment: I mean using chrome 28 browser with `keyup()`, cursor always moves to the end. :( are you able to reproduce that?

Comment: @DKM: this always happens when you reassign the value. You have to remember the cursor position, assign the value and then restore the position. I told you it's complicated! ;)